# how to let an object add itself to an array

Tags: javascript

I'm making a maze solving algorithm. But I want to let the squares of the maze add themselves to an array so I can sort off in a 'group' and make the solving faster but I ran into a problem when trying to add the square. So I was wondering if there's a way to let an object add itself inside a function of itself.

```
Class Square {
  constructor() {

  }
  addToGroup(arrayOfGroup){
    arrayOfGroup.push(this.square);
  }
}
```

Of course, I found that this doesn't work. What I want to do is get the array back with the square object inside.

Comment: Try: `arrayOfGroup.push(this);`

Comment: Just push `this` and not `this.square`

Answer (score 3):

You were quite close. You had 3 issues:

1. mispelling `class` for `Class`
2. you wrote `this.square`. But inside a class, `this` is already a reference to the object itself.
3. not returning the array (if you want it to be returned...)

```js
class Square { // <--------------------- issue 1 
  constructor() {
  }
  addToGroup(arrayOfGroup) {
    arrayOfGroup.push(this) // <-------- issue 2
    return arrayOfGroup // <------------ issue 3
  }
}
let square = new Square()
let group = []

console.log(square.addToGroup(group))
```

---

I guess the third issue may not be one, depending on my understanding of your question:

> what I want to do is get the array back with the square object inside.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying I didn't know that I could just use arrayOfGroup.push(this)

Comment: If this answers your question, you [may accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). And you are welcome :)